# The norm or the singular values of the sum of identity matrix and a rank-$1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $N \times N$ rank-$1$ matrix. I am interested in finding the norm or the maximum singular value of $(A-cI)$ where $I$ is $N \times N$ identity matrix and $c>0$ is a scalar constant.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please show your try at the question and where you're stuck in order to get positive response from the community instead of down votes.

Answer (score 1):

If $N=1$ then $\|A-cI\| = |A-c|$.

Assume that $N>1$.

Note that since $\ker A $ is non trivial have $(A-cI)x = -cx$ for some 
non zero $x$, and so $\|A-cI\| \ge |c|$.

If $A$ is rank one it can be written as $A=u v^T$ for two vectors $u,v$. Without loss of generality we can take $\|u\| = 1$.

If $u,v$ are colinear, then $A=k u u^T$, for some $k$, and the eigenvalues of
the symmetric $A$ are $k,0$, hence $\|A-cI\| = \max(|c|,|k-c|)$.

Assume that $u,v$ are not colinear (equivalently, they are linearly independent).

Now assume that $N=2$. The $N>2$ case will be dealt with subsequently.

Let $B=(uv^T -c I) (v^Tu-cI) = v v^T +c^2I -c(u v^T + v u^T)$. We want to compute 
$\sqrt{\lambda_\max(B)}$.

Note that $\lambda_\max(B) = c^2+\lambda_\max(C)$, where $C=v v^T -c(u v^T + v u^T)$.

In the basis $u,v$, the matrix $C$ has the representation
$\begin{bmatrix} -c u^Tv & -c \|v\|^2 \\
u^T v - c & \|v\|^2-c u^T v
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -c \|v\|^2 \\
u^T v - c & \|v\|^2
\end{bmatrix} - c u^TvI$.
The eigenvalues of the last matrix are
${1 \over 2} (\|v\|^2 \pm \sqrt{\|v\|^4+4 \|v\|^2c(c-u^Tv)})$, and hence
the eigenvalues of $B$ (which are non negative) are
${1 \over 2} (\|v\|^2 \pm \sqrt{\|v\|^4+4 \|v\|^2c(c-u^Tv)}) +c (c-u^Tv)$. Hence
$\|A-cI\| = \sqrt{{1 \over 2} (\|v\|^2 + \sqrt{\|v\|^4+4 \|v\|^2c(c-u^Tv)}) + c(c-u^Tv)}$.

If $N>2$, then $B$ has additional eigenvalues at $c^2$, hence the formula remains the same, since we know that the norm of $A-cI$ restricted to the subspace 
$\operatorname{sp}\{u,v\}$ is no less than $|c|$.

Comment: @user1551: Who said it was zero?

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat